# Getting value of LSB from Hex (C code)

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I've got a code like this in C:

```
unsigned char const data[ ] = {0x0a, 0x1d, 0xf0, 0x07};
```

I need to extract it such that the final value is:

```
0xa1df7
```

I have only been able to extract and get it working if the hex values that have at least 1 zero:

```
unsigned char const data[ ] = {0x0a, 0xd0, 0xf0, 0x07};
```

using the code below:

```
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
{
    tmp = data[i];
    if ( (data[i] <= 0x0F) &&  (((data[i] & 0x0F) == 0) || (data[i] & 0xF0) == 0)) // one of the hex is zero
    {
        tmp = ((tmp << 4) >> 4) << N[i];
        std::cout << "foo: " << std::hex << tmp << ":" << std::endl;    

    }
    else if ((data[i] >= 0x0F) &&  (((data[i] & 0x0F) == 0) || (data[i] & 0xF0) == 0) )
    {
        tmp = (tmp >> 4) << N[i];
        std::cout << "bar: " << std::hex << tmp << ":" << std::endl;

    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "result: " << std::hex << result << ":" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "tmp << 8: " << std::hex << (tmp << 8)<< ":" << std::endl;
        result = result | (tmp << 8);
        std::cout << "result |= (tmp << 8): " << std::hex << result << ":" << std::endl;
    }

    result |= tmp;
    std::cout << "boo: " << std::hex << result << ":" << std::endl;
}
```

It seems the last else {...} block is troublesome for me. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The final value from that array does not make sense. What kind of input values are they, and why should they lead to that final value?

Comment: Thanks Christoffer. 0xa1df7 is value from the array such that every '0' is removed in each element of the array.
For the case of {0x0a, 0xd0, 0xf0, 0x07}, the output would is - 0xadf7.

Comment: What is `N[]` and why aren't you using it in the `else` clause where you're having problems?

Comment: Greg - hi. int N[ ] = {12,8,4,0};

Comment: Doing (last else block)-
else
{
    tmp = (tmp << 8) << N[i];
}
gives me 1da0f7. I am trying to get a1df7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned char const data[ ] = {0x0a, 0x1d, 0xf0, 0x07};

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    int i,r = 0;
    for(i=0; i<sizeof(data); i++){
        if(data[i] & 0xf0) r = (r<<4) + (data[i]>>4);
        if(data[i] & 0x0f) r = (r<<4) + (data[i]&0x0f);
    }
    printf("%x\n",r);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs "a1df7"

Comment: always great if 30 lines+ of code can be reduced to just a few ;^)

Answer (score 0):

You'd better convert it all to a hex string first ("0a1df007") and then delete all zeroes :)

Comment: not the easiest...since you'll have to convert the hexstring back to an integer. It seems like an overly complicated way of doing things

Answer (score 0):

```
 unsigned char const data[ ] = {0x0a, 0x1d, 0xf0, 0x07};

 unsigned int value=0;
 for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
 {
     int nibble = (data[i] & 0xf0) >> 4;
     if(nibble > 0)
     {
          value<<=4;
          value += nibble;
     }
     nibble = data[i] & 0x0f;
     if(nibble > 0)
     {
          value<<=4;
          value += nibble;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char const data[ ] = {0x0a, 0x1d, 0xf0, 0x07};
```

Uhm, but that looks like a plain network byte order.

For 32bit int, do something like:

```
unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)data;
int val = (p[0]<<24) | (p[1]<<16) | (p[2]<<8) | p[3];
```

And similarly for 64bit values.

P.S. Be careful about sign. In some cases explicit conversion to a signed type is required to force sign bit extension.

Comment: That's not right. The required output is 'a1df7'. Thanks however.

Comment: explain to me how 0x000a1df7 is different from 0xa1df7? or you need string? - `printf("%x\n", val)` - as %x strips leading zeros by default.